# How to trigger a function after typed a single letter in kendo combobox?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use angular ken-do_combo box as an auto-complete..

How to trigger an event while typed a single letter in angular-ken do combobox.

But i cant get the event while typing a letter in combobox

Answer (score 0):

Hey don't know if you are still looking for this but try putting a scope variable on the combobox:

```
<input kendo-combo-box="kendoCombo"/>
<script>
   angular.controller("kendoCtlr", ["$scope", function($scope){
     console.log($scope.kendoCombo.text());
    }
   ]
  );
</script>
```